# .replace after adding a variable via .html doesnt apply

Tags: jquery, replace

http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/UusLH/

```
$( document ).ready(function calculate() {
    var yearly_total_value = parseFloat(10.5);
    $('.yearly-total-value').html(yearly_total_value);
    $('.yearly-total-value').text().replace('.',',');
});
```

This is the shorten snippet from my calculate function, since Im in germany I need a comma than a dot. But the dot is needed for the calulations.
Tried it first with `$('.yearly-total-value').text().replace('.',',')` in the chromedevtools console and it works fine. But in script the replace doesnt apply. Also

Any ideas or suggestions?

best regards
denym

Comment: .replace() return replaced value, but not set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text back.

```
$('.yearly-total-value').text($('.yearly-total-value').text().replace('.',','));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it directly ?

```
$('.yearly-total-value').text(parseFloat(10.5).toString().replace('.',','));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UusLH/3/)

If for some reason you *have* to do it after appending the content:

```
$('.yearly-total-value').text(function(_,txt)  { return txt.replace('.',','); });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UusLH/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to invoke replace() like a jquery function. But it's not part of jquery and can only be applied to a string: <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/UusLH/2/</kbd>

```
$( document ).ready(function calculate() {
    var yearly_total_value = ''+parseFloat(10.5);
    $('.yearly-total-value').html(yearly_total_value.replace('.',','));
});
```